# Build FreeBSD Docker image using Ubuntu host OS

Tags: docker, linux

I know that in generally it is impossible to build FreeBSD Docker image on Linux host OS due to different kernels and sys calls. [Relevant discussion](https://forums.docker.com/t/trouble-when-i-want-to-used-freebsd-images/3309/2).

However, I would like to know maybe there is a simple workaround to overcome this limitation?

P.S. I don't want to consider Vagrant usage inside Docker container and I don't want to consider usage of FreeBSD as host OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can't build a docker image for an arm kernel from a x86 one neither.

Nor can't you build an image with a glibc lib targetting a 4.x kernel on a host running a 3.X kernel.

Docker isolate processes and give a virtual filesystem but that's still the host kernel who own the process, so obviously without a layer of hardware virtualization like virtualbox, vmware, xen, kvm, there's no chance to build an image with binaries made for a different kernel type.